# How to convert one JSON format to another?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I want to convert a particular JSON to another JSON. I have been trying with the 'reduce' function but I am not able to get desired output.
I have this JSON -

```
"q_6348":{
      "rowmumaopt_20639":[
         {
            "Q":[
               "Q"
            ]
         },
         {
            "R":[
               "R"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "rowmumaopt_20640":[
         {
            "S":[
               "S"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "rowmumaopt_20641":[
         {
            "R":[
               "R"
            ]
         },
         {
            "Q":[
               "Q"
            ]
         }
      ]
}
```

And I want something like this -

```
"q_6348":{
      "rowmumaopt_20639":{
            "Q":[
               "Q"
            ],
            "R":[
               "R"
            ]
      },
      "rowmumaopt_20640":{
            "S":[
               "S"
            ]
      },
      "rowmumaopt_20641":{
            "R":[
               "R"
            ],
            "Q":[
               "Q"
            ]
      }
}
```

I am stuck on this since long. Please help...

Comment: use a couple bog-standard loops and Object.keys, show what you have tried with reduce

Comment: You have not shown your work and what's not working. It feels like you are asking us to write your code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```js
const input = {
  "q_6348": {
    "rowmumaopt_20639": [
      { "Q": [ "Q" ] },
      { "R": [ "R" ] }
    ],
    "rowmumaopt_20640": [
      { "S": [ "S" ] }
    ],
    "rowmumaopt_20641": [
      { "R": [ "R" ] },
      { "Q": [ "Q" ] }
    ]
  }
};

const merge = (obj, ...rest) => rest.length ? {...obj, ...(merge(...rest))} : obj;

for (let i in input) {
  for (let j in input[i]) {
    input[i][j] = merge(...input[i][j]);
  }
}

console.dir(input, { depth: null });
```

Comment: This line (merge(...rest)) giving error. "A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter"

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to merge `input[n][o]` from array of objects into one serialized object.

Since you have an enumerable keys in the array objects, you can easily merge them with [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

E.g. (Improved from Wyck's answer)

```js
const input = {
  "q_6348": {
    "rowmumaopt_20639": [
      { "Q": [ "Q" ] },
      { "R": [ "R" ] }
    ],
    "rowmumaopt_20640": [
      { "S": [ "S" ] }
    ],
    "rowmumaopt_20641": [
      { "R": [ "R" ] },
      { "Q": [ "Q" ] }
    ]
  }
};

for (const i in input) {
  for (const j in input[i]) {
    input[i][j] = Object.assign(...input[i][j]);
  }
}

console.dir(input, { depth: null });
```

Comment: I am getting error on this line
(...input[i][j])
Its saying "A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter."
I am using typescript.

Comment: @Guccho Can you try adding `compilerOptions.downlevelIteration: true`  in your tsconfig.json?

Comment: Excellent improvement!  Now, I feel a bit silly for making it more complicated than it needed to be in my answer.  But I learned something, and I guess that's what it's all about!  :)